# Publish dot net core web application to the linux server

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I have copied my dot net core published project to the linux server (ubuntu 16.04) with the help of this link [Set up a hosting environment for ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx, and deploy to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction).

But when I tried to browse the url with port 5004 it shows nothing there (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).
Why is it not working ? To get my dot net core application running on linux server - do I need to just copy my published folder to the server or do I have to create project there and then dotnet publish and restore?
When I tried to run dotnet myproject.dll, I got below error:

> A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required
>   to execute the application was not found in '/var/aspnetcore/myproject

Comment: What was the exact publish command that you ran?

Comment: No command! I am doing by VS2015. @omajid